# Function to apply a nested clusters to class "dist"

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` called `mydf`.

```
x y
0 A
1 A
2 A
3 A
0 B
2 B
0 C
3 C
3 D
...(20,000 rows)
```

I am using the `GMD` package (elbow method) to automatically identify clusters and decide the number of clusters.

```
library("GMD")
dist.obj <- dist(mydf$x[mydf$y=="A"]) 
hclust.obj <- hclust(dist.obj)
css.obj <- css.hclust(dist.obj,hclust.obj)
elbow.obj <- elbow.batch(css.obj)
k <- elbow.obj$k
cutree.obj <- cutree(hclust.obj,k=k)
mydf$cluster <- cutree.obj
```

I would like to apply those scripts for all categories (A, B, C, D, etc) in column y automatically, don't need to repeat the scripts one after one.

Problem 1: I got the error "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2.1 Gb" when process this step:

```
css.obj <- css.hclust(dist.obj,hclust.obj)
```

Problem 2: I can process this, but am stuck and can't get any further.

```
dist.obj <- lapply(split(mydf, mydf$y), dist)
```

The desired result for `mydf` is

```
x  y cluster
0 A   1  
1 A   1
2 A   2
3 A   3
0 B   1
2 B   2
0 C   1
3 C   2
3 D   1
```

Can you please help me? Any solution is well appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: The first (and second) lines throw errors (as expected). So are you having trouble reading error messages?